# YAML Config - best way to replace symbols within a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, symbols

I have a configuration file in YAML format with some paths in my rails applications like this:

```
config
    :path1: /a/b/c
    :path2: /a/:id/c
```

path1 doesn't helps too much. I need that every time I use config[:path2] to somehow replace the :id with a value I have. It is possible?

Hope this was clear enough.
Thanks!

Comment: I did a function that replaces the :id with the value I need but I wanted a better / more flexible way of doing this... such as just using config[:path2] and somehow replace that symbol in it with my value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bit of ERB.

```
# config.yml
config
    :path1: /a/b/c
    :path2: /a/<%= id %>/c
    :path3: <%= path3 %>
```

and

```
id = "23"
path3 = "hello/world"

t = ERB.new(File.read("config.yml"))
c = YAML.load(t.result(binding).to_s)

c["config"][:path2]
# => /a/23/c
c["config"][:path3]
# => /hello/world
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even if it doesn't help in my situation where :id changes a lot after the application started...